# Take data from different datasets and inserting them into a SQL table from SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, insert, dataset

I have a SSRS report with 20 different datasets with some calculated columns in each.
I want to take few fields from all data sets including some calculated columns and insert them into a SQL table.
I want to do this for each month so that I can see the trends during a period. Is there any way to do that with out editing the data sets?
Can I refer the fields that I need by referring to Textbox4 and insert them into a SQL table? What is the easy way to do without touching data sets?

Comment: you are better off using SSIS to achieve want you want rather than SSRS

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely alot better solution than using SSRS to update a SQL database. I am not proposing this as the *best* solution but rather a way to achieve what was asked.

You could create a dataset that runs a stored procedure you can pass the data as parameters to. The Sproc would do the insert into your chosen table and you can pass in the parameters from your original dataset however you see fit. You could even setup a second report with the Stored procedure Dataset that you can call on command by having an action event on an item to call the report. (I had a subreport embedded in a column of a tablix configured so it would only update with values from that row for instance).

To clarify:

- Create a subreport that accepts the data you want to insert as a parameter for each column
- Instead of adding a normal Dataset, have it call a stored procedure that inserts as you require
- Add the subreport to your main report to be called once its run and configure the required parameters to be passed through.

There will be better, more efficient, cleaner ways to do this, but I found the above to work for my purposes since I was limited by time and resources. But I would still recommend you seek other solutions if possible.

[image: Screenshot of example]